# Why can't I login into Ask Ubuntu with launchpad anymore?

Tags: support, launchpad

I do have an Ubuntu Launchpad account (still works, e.g. for reporting bugs, etc.) and I used to use it to login into Ask Ubuntu as well.

For some months now, I can't login into Ask Ubuntu anymore. After authorizing to launchpad, which still works, password OK, and choosing the access level, I do get an error message from Ask Ubuntu that login failed.

The Ubuntu customer service could not help, they don't even understand the problem.

I'm logged in here with my Google Account instead of Launchpad right now, but the question remains: Is there anyone in charge and able to fix this?

**Compliciation:** I do know that this question belongs to meta.askubuntu.com, but this site requires me to have 5 or more reputation points, which I do not have with this workaround google account. So one is never able to ask on meta.askubuntu.com, why authentication on askubuntu.com wouldn't work, since this requirement breaks itself by design.

regards
Hadmut

Comment: "but this site requires me to have 5 or more reputation points, "  that takes milliseconds to achieve. plus that is still no reason to mis-use AU.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You may suggest edits to 3 questions, such as fix typos like "i am" to "I am", and get 2x3=6 reputation points. See the [site help on reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) for more. Check out the [general site help](https://meta.askubuntu.com/help) too.